# How to target all but the first tag in css3?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This is my html

```
<div class="app-screens">
    <a href="./includes/images/taaid/Screenshot_2013-12-08-15-00-37.png" data-title="TA AID" data-lightbox="taaid">
        <img src="./includes/images/taaid/Screenshot_2013-12-08-15-00-37.png"/>
    </a>
    <a href="./includes/images/taaid/Screenshot_2013-12-08-15-02-16.png" data-title="TA AID" data-lightbox="taaid">
        <img src="./includes/images/taaid/Screenshot_2013-12-08-15-02-16.png"/>
    </a>
    <a href="./includes/images/taaid/Screenshot_2013-12-08-15-03-38.png" data-title="TA AID" data-lightbox="taaid">
        <img src="./includes/images/taaid/Screenshot_2013-12-08-15-03-38.png"/>
    </a>
    <a href="./includes/images/taaid/Screenshot_2013-12-08-15-06-19.png" data-title="TA AID" data-lightbox="taaid">
        <img src="./includes/images/taaid/Screenshot_2013-12-08-15-06-19.png"/>
    </a>
    <a href="./includes/images/taaid/Screenshot_2013-12-08-15-06-29.png" data-title="TA AID" data-lightbox="taaid">
        <img src="./includes/images/taaid/Screenshot_2013-12-08-15-06-29.png"/>
    </a>
    <a href="./includes/images/taaid/Screenshot_2013-12-08-15-06-45.png" data-title="TA AID" data-lightbox="taaid">
        <img src="./includes/images/taaid/Screenshot_2013-12-08-15-06-45.png"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

and my css

```
.app-screens img:not(:first-child) { 
    display: none;
}
```

I want to hide all the img tags except the first. But they all still show... Does anyone know whats wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of img:not(:first-child) you have to use a:not(:first-child).

CSS:

```
.app-screens a:not(:first-child) { 
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
.app-screens a:not(:first-child) img { 
    display: none;
}
```

You have to target the `anchors` before then the image.

Answer (score 1):

You  can try this:

<kbd>Demo[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_j/n5fn2L47/)</kbd>

```
.app-screens a:not(:first-child) { 
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, you can do this with CSS2, in case you wanted to support more browsers:

```
.app-screens a img { display: none; }
.app-screens a:first-child img { display: block; }
```